# Dynamically adding jQuery Tabs and FullCalendars from database

Tags: c#, jquery, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4, fullcalendar

I have a View with jquery tabs in it, each tab holding a FullCalendar object. Each fullcalender is populated with events for a specific employee. This all works fine. The thing is, I want to add a new tab and a new calendar inside that tab whenever I add a new employee to the database. I'm not sure how to go about it, any advice would be great! I didn't include code as I don't think its very relevant but I certainly will if need be.
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple what you have to do is dynamically add you lis and divs as below. You have to write a SQL to get the count of the employees from the database. Then loop as below.

```
for(count of the employees taken from the db){
  <li><a href="#tabs-count">EMP count</a></li>}

for(count of the employees taken from the db)
  {
     add divs here
  }
```

Inside the divs you can write whatever you want.

This is the basic logic and how it should be done.

Comment: right makes sense, any idea how I could dynamically add the fullcalendar in each tab as i create it though?

Comment: add tp the div you creating inside the for loop

Comment: the fullcalendar is added through jquery, any idea how I would go about looping through that for each count of employee taken from db?